# Azure function written in python has 500 when "id" binding points doesn't have a corrseponding item in cosmosDB collection

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have been experimenting with azure functions using python. I have followed the guide found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#http-trigger-look-up-id-from-query-string-python. This works fine, I can query the enpoint using `?id=0` and I get the correct response. Although as soon as I replace the 0 with an id that is not present in my cosmos db in azure it throws a 500. The corresponding javascript example works.

Stack trace:

```
[9/17/19 5:53:18 PM] Executed 'Functions.HttpReader' (Failed, Id=23f0d832-5d00-4ffc-a5b9-3e20fed1c105)
[9/17/19 5:53:18 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpReader. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[9/17/19 5:53:18 PM] Exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
[9/17/19 5:53:18 PM] Stack:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools/2.7.1585/workers/python/deps/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 294, in _handle__invocation_request
[9/17/19 5:53:18 PM]     pytype=pb_type_info.pytype)
[9/17/19 5:53:18 PM]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools/2.7.1585/workers/python/deps/azure_functions_worker/bindings/meta.py", line 63, in from_incoming_proto
[9/17/19 5:53:18 PM]     return binding.decode(datum, trigger_metadata=metadata)
[9/17/19 5:53:18 PM]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools/2.7.1585/workers/python/deps/azure/functions/cosmosdb.py", line 23, in decode
[9/17/19 5:53:18 PM]     data_type = data.type
[9/17/19 5:53:18 PM] .
```

Code:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, doc: func.DocumentList) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.warn('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    if not doc:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Not found",
            status_code=404
        )
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            body=doc[0].to_json(),
            status_code=200
        )
```

function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "doc",
      "databaseName": "<my-cosmos>",
      "collectionName": "<my-col>",
      "connectionStringSetting": "<conn-string>",
      "direction": "in",
      "id": "{Query.id}"
    }
  ]
}
```

To me this seems like a bug, but I am feel like I need a sanity check.

So is this a bug? Or have I messed something up?

Comment: Are you passing string values to the id?

Comment: I am querying it as shown above with `?id=0`. I am unsure if this gets interpreted as a string or a number as it happens outside of my function. Did I understand your question correctly? @MatiasQuaranta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. This looks like a bug in the Python library that does the conversion into a `func.Document`.  I confirmed the below code works as expected in JavaScript:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (context.bindings.document == null)
    {
        context.res = {
            statusCode: 400
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.res = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: context.bindings.document
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks for surfacing.  [Opened this issue to track](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/548)

If wanting to do this pattern in Python currently you'd have to not use input bindings and fetch the document using the CosmosDB python SDK based on the query parameter.